# Producing animation with DSolve

Tags: plotting, differential-equations, animation

I'm teaching an intro differential equations class and trying to teach my students about bifurcation diagrams. I'd like to give an animation which shows how a solution changes as we change a parameter. I have the following animation which gives the bifurcation diagram on the left and a vector field on the right. I would like to overlay the solution to the IVP
$$\frac{dx}{dt} = \frac{x(x-5)}{100} + s;\; x(1)=1 $$
on the vector field (planning to use `Show` once I have the solution).
I am struggling to get the solution using `Manipulate`.

My current code that is working and *almost* gives what I want is:

```
Export["bifurcation-ex.gif",
 Animate[GraphicsRow[{Show[
     Plot[x /. Solve[0 == x*(x - 5)/100 + s, x], {s, -2, 1}],
     ParametricPlot[{S, t}, {t, -15, 20}, PlotStyle -> Red]],
    VectorPlot[{x, x*(x - 5)/100 + S}, {x, -20, 20}, {y, -2, 2}]}],
  {S, -2, 1, .1}, AnimationDirection -> ForwardBackward]]
```

The code which is problematic is

```
Manipulate[
 soln = DSolve[{x'[t] == x[t]*(x[t] - 5)/100 + s, x[0] == 1}, x[t], t];
 Plot[x[t] /. soln, {t, -20, 20}, PlotRange -> {{-20, 20}, {-2, 2}}],
 {s, -2, 1/16}]
```

It works fine when I first evaluate but when I try to move the slider to adjust the parameter $s$, I sometimes get a warning
`Solve: Inverse functions are being used by Solve, so some solutions may not be found; use Reduce for complete solution information`. I looked at the documentation for Reduce, and I am confused at how to use it to get my desired result. Does anyone know how I can go about this? Thanks!

Comment: Try replacing

`soln = DSolve[{x'[t] == x[t]*(x[t] - 5)/100 + s, x[0] == 1}, x[t], t];`

with

`soln = NDSolve[{x'[t] == x[t]*(x[t] - 5)/100 + s, x[0] == 1}, x[t], {t,-20,20}];`